# PHP - Prettier one-line if

Tags: php

Is there a prettier way to do this in PHP?

```
$a = isset($a) ? $a : $b;
```

In Python I'd do something like:

```
a = a or b
```

Comment: no . this is the syntax .

Comment: I tried to find something similar to ``a = a or b``, but didn't either.

Comment: What you want to do ?

Comment: I don't understand why your question was downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't.

It has been discussed by the PHP devs as a possible feature for future versions - [See here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ifsetor) - but has been rejected.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using php>=5.3 you can do it little more prettier:

```
$a = isset($a) ?: $b;
```

**EDIT**:
In this case `isset($a)` is a problem, because if `isset($a)` return `true`, then `$a` will be set to `true`. You can consider to change it to

```
$a = isset($a) ?: $b;
```

But be careful if `$a == false || $a == 0` then `$a` will be set to `$b`

Comment: This would set $a to true if it exists.

Comment: ah. good catch @Dogbert i was focusing on making the syntax more terse and actually ignored what it would do!

Answer (score 0):

Since 5.3 you can do:

```
$a = isset($a) ?: $b;
```

**edit**

as mentioned in the comments - this will actually make `$a` equal to true (as a result of `isset`) rather than the value of `$a`

Comment: This would set `$a` to true if it exists.